# How can I transpose and "untranspose" a matrix?

Tags: algorithm, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

and I transpose the matrix:

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

How can I get the original matrix back, after the transpose?

```
"untranspose" =
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

I am making a simple cryptographic algorithm in Java and need that to solve that problem.

Comment: The answer lies in your question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You simply transpose the matrix again.

Description of the transposition operation properties:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose#Properties

Comment: more formally it is called involution, like "Transposition is involution" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_(mathematics))

Comment: @Andrey: Thanks for the specification. I think that calling transpose an operation isn't a mistake though, is it?

Answer (score 1):

If some linear algebra review might help, recall that `U = (U^t)^t` where U is your matrix and t is the symbol for the transpose operation

In short, you just flip the indices again, to get back the original matrix.

and nope... LaTeX does not work on StackOverflow :(